# Javascript use original array when creating subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

I am new to Javascript and I have encountered the following problem:

I have an array of objects that remains unchanged. From this array, I would like to create subarrays with different start and end indexes.

```
var origArr = [o1, o2, o3, o4, o5];
// origArr .length = 5
var subArr = origArr.slice(1, 4);
// subArr  = [o2, o3, o4];
```

Normally I can use the slice method. But this means that the elements are copied into the new array. Since all I want to do is the alter the start and end index, is there any easy way to do this without creating a new copy each time? I would just use the reference to the original array.

Thank you for your help.

Chris

Comment: If you want to modify the original array, you will have to use `.pop()` and `.shift()`.

Comment: Do you mean modify the original array?

Comment: Are you looking for an object that would be a view into the original array, so `origArr[2] = 0` would cause `subArr[1]` to be 0 as well? There's nothing built-in for that. You could write your own wrapper object for it, although it might be slower than just using a slice.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Can you give us a bigger picture ? We may suggest an algorithm then.

Comment: The subarray is used as an argument to a function from another library. As the user changes the value of the slider, the length of the subarray (time period) being passed changes. So really the range of data that is passed to the function changes, but the elements stay unchanged.

Comment: For now, I can keep the start index fixed at 0 and only change the length of the array, but I do not wish to lose any data if truncation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a "view" of a subset of an array with standard JavaScript arrays. You *can* do it with the new [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), but the new typed arrays only offer storage for various numeric formats. Your variable names (`o1` and so on) suggest object references instead.

For standard arrays, you can use a function instead:

```
function subMapper(array, index, length) {
    return function(i, value) {
        if (index + i >= length) {
            // Beyond the end of the array, do what you think is appropriate
        }
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            // Getting a value
            return array[index + i];
        }
        // Setting a value
        array[index + i] = value;
    };
}

var origArr = [o1, o2, o3, o4, o5];
var subArrMapper = subMapper(origArr, 1, 4);
var x = subMapper(0);
console.log(x === o2); // true
```